# Is it necessary to play Crysis Warhead in order to enjoy the full game experience?

Tags: crysis, crysis-warhead

I want to buy *Crysis*, but I see there are *Crysis,* *Crysis Warhead*, and *Crysis Max Edition*. The thing here is that *Crysis Warhead* has a multiplayer component, but does it add anything extra to the story of *Crysis*, or does it only add multiplayer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Crysis Warhead* isn't a multiplayer component. It's a fully single-player game, in fact, telling the story from the viewpoint of Psycho, with *in my humble opinion* better gameplay than the original.

You're talking about *Crysis Wars*, which is a separate game bundled with *Warhead*, as its multiplayer component. This is in contrast with *Crysis* where the multiplayer was integrated.

I would say getting *Warhead* is definitely worth it to add to the story **and** have a multiplayer game.

Comment: Oh!!! ok thank you very much ... I think I was missunderstanding Crysis Warhead. I should buy then the Maximum edition in order to play it completely. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: +1, Warhead was the first real game in the series, the first Crysis was a tech demo more than anything.